# In the simplest way possible - could someone explain the rule you followed in spotting the error?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Basically the sentence flowed well enough for me not to notice the error.

This is the sentence:

> More importantly was the renaissance discovery of the literature of classical Greece.

I now know that the error is "importantly" and that it should be replaced with "important".

Can someone please explain how I could have spotted that "importantly" needed to be replaced with "important"?

Comment: Also please be aware that "could of" is incorrect; [it should be "could have".](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/264958/what-is-the-difference-between-couldve-and-could-of)

Answer (score 3):

One proofreading technique is to ignore any modifiers that aren't grammatically essential:

> * <s>More</s> importantly was the <s>renaissance</s> discovery <s>of the literature</s> <s>of classical Greece</s>. 
>   * Importantly was the discovery.

Another technique is to restore canonical order, placing subjects, verbs and arguments in their usual locations:

> * The renaissance discovery of the literature of classical Greece was more importantly.

A combination of these techniques is quite effective:

> * The discovery was importantly.

Answer (score 1):

The subject of the sentence you wrote is "renaissance discovery". Notice how this is a noun. The discovery is what is being described. Therefore, the adjective form is necessary in this case.

It's easier to see if we invert the sentence, like this:

> "The Renaissance discovery of the literature of classical Greece was more **important**"

Notice that we cannot use "importantly" here.